# Getting reference to object that run function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery extension to check if servers are alive or not. 
Extension in here: https://gist.github.com/jerone/3487795

My code so far:

```html
    // Device scanner class
        function deviceScanner(list){
                this.list = list;
                this.totalDevices = list.length;
                this.scan = function () {
                        
                        for(var i = 0; i < this.totalDevices; i++){
                                
                                $.Ping(list[i],1000)
                                        .done( function(success, url, time, on) {
                                            found(url);
                                        })
                                        .fail( function(success, url, time, on) {
                                            notFound(url);
                                        });  
                        }
                }
                
                this.found = function (address){
                        alert(address);       
                }
                this.notFound = function (address){
                        alert(address);       
                }
        }
      
      var scanner = new deviceScanner([KVMRxDefaultIP, KVMTx1DefaultIP, KVMTx2DefaultIP]);
      
      $("#bt1").click(function(){
                scanner.scan();
        });
```

How shall i make Ping done or fail store result in deviceScanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    // Device scanner class
        function deviceScanner(list){
                var me = this;  // HERE (1)
                this.list = list;
                this.totalDevices = list.length;
                this.scan = function () {
                        
                        for(var i = 0; i < this.totalDevices; i++){
                                
                                $.Ping(list[i],1000)
                                        .done( function(success, url, time, on) {
                                            me.property_done = true; // HERE (2)
                                            found(url);
                                        })
                                        .fail( function(success, url, time, on) {
                                            me.property_failed = true; // HERE (3)
                                            notFound(url);
                                        });  
                        }
                }
                
                this.found = function (address){
                        alert(address);       
                }
                this.notFound = function (address){
                        alert(address);       
                }
        }
      
      var scanner = new deviceScanner([KVMRxDefaultIP, KVMTx1DefaultIP, KVMTx2DefaultIP]);
      
      $("#bt1").click(function(){
                scanner.scan();
        });
```

Comment: @KrzysztofBoksa: Please mark it as the "Answer" if it answers your question! Thanks.